# Calculate sequence identity of two sequences of equal length

Tags: python

I'm a newbie to python so I would really appreciate some help. I have a list of sequences, e.g. sequences = ['AUUGCAUG', 'CGUGGCUA']

I now have to 1. determine the length of each sequence and calculate the number of matches at each position of the sequences using *while* and *index*.

This is what I have so far:

```
def compute_sequence_identity(sequence_a, sequence_b):
    
    length_a = len(sequence_a)
    
    length_b = len(sequence_b)
    
    if length_a != length_b:
    
        print("Sequences are not of equal length.")
    
    if length_a == length_b:
    
        i = 0
        num_matches = 0
        while i < num_matches:
            i = i + 1
    
sequence_identity = compute_sequence_identity(sequences[0], sequences[1])
     
print("Sequence identity: " + str(sequence_identity) + "%")
```

But the answer I get is `"Sequence identy: None%"`.

Can someone please help me out?

Comment: Your function doesn't return anything

Comment: add `return num_matches` at the end of your function.

Comment: Also, you are comparing `i < num_matches` but they both start from 0

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem is that you're not returning anything from the function (i.e. you need a `return` statement.

```
def compute_sequence_identity(sequence_a, sequence_b):
    length_a = len(sequence_a)
    length_b = len(sequence_b)

    if length_a != length_b:
        # print("Sequences are not of equal length.")
        # print() doesn't return anything!
        return None # Replace "None" here with whatever you want the function to return in this case (i.e. where the sequences don't match)
    # if length_a == length_b:
    else: # Better to just use an else-statement here to avoid ambiguity
        i = 0
        num_matches = 0
        while i < length_a: # You want to iterate over the whole sequence, presumably, so we want the stop condition to be the length of the sequences, not num_matches
            if sequence_a[i] == sequence_b[i]: # Check for a match
                num_matches += 1 # Increment match counter if they do match!
            i = i + 1 # Increment index so we check the next item in the next loop

        return 100 * num_matches / length_a # I don't know if you want to multiply by 100 here for a percentage or not, but I assume so from the below print statement

sequence_identity = compute_sequence_identity(sequences[0], sequences[1])
 
print("Sequence identity: " + str(sequence_identity) + "%")
```

So, we begin by calculating the lengths of both sequences, then we check for being in one of two states: 1) Sequences are different lengths, in which case we abort (or `return` some other value, as you like). 2) The sequences are the same length (the only other possible state), and we calculate the percentage of their elements which match up.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that nothing is returned from the function and the number of matches is not computed in the while loop.

```
def compute_sequence_identity(sequence_a, sequence_b):
    length_a = len(sequence_a)

    length_b = len(sequence_b)

    if length_a == length_b:

        i = 0
        num_matches = 0
        while i < len(sequence_a):
            if sequence_a[i] == sequence_b[i]:
                num_matches+= 1
            i = i + 1
        return num_matches / i
    else:
        print("Sequences are not of equal length.")
        return None

sequences = ['AUUGCAUG', 'CGUGGCUA']
sequence_identity = compute_sequence_identity(sequences[0], sequences[1])

print("Sequence identity: " + str(sequence_identity) + "%")
```

There are probably better way to do this. like with a for loop

```
def compute_sequence_identity(sequence_a, sequence_b):
    if len(sequence_a) == len(sequence_b): 
        num_matches = 0
        for i in range(len(sequence_a)):
            if sequence_a[i] == sequence_b[i]:
                num_matches+= 1
        return num_matches / len(sequence_a)
    else:
        print("Sequences are not of equal length.")
        return None

sequences = ['AUUGCAUG', 'CGUGGCUA']
sequence_identity = compute_sequence_identity(sequences[0], sequences[1]) 
print("Sequence identity: " + str(sequence_identity) + "%")
```

or with list comprehension

```
def compute_sequence_identity(sequence_a, sequence_b):
    if len(sequence_a) == len(sequence_b):
        return sum([sequence_a[i] == sequence_b[i] for i in range(len(sequence_a))]) / len(sequence_a)
    else:
        print("Sequences are not of equal length.")
        return None

sequences = ['AUUGCAUG', 'CGUGGCUA']
sequence_identity = compute_sequence_identity(sequences[0], sequences[1])
print("Sequence identity: " + str(sequence_identity) + "%")
```